# Javascript not working direct condition while indirect conditioning works

Tags: javascript

I have a old java script code which i want to optimize. The thing is if i try to combine statements then the script is not working.

I have tried removing multiple if condition into one and then run.

Working old block:

```
var xx=1;
    if (objRDF == '' || objRDT == '') {
xx=0;        
    }
if (xx==0){
errString = errString + "message here";}
var yy=1;
//RDT and RDF are data values.
    if (RDT < RDF) {
yy=0;
    }
if(yy==0){
        errString = errString + "message here";
}
alert (errstring);
```

Nice little alert comes up with this code.

**New Block:**

```
if (objRDF == '' || objRDT == '') {
errString = errString + "message here";
}
if (RDT < RDF) {
errString = errString + "message here";
}
    alert (errstring);
```

**No alert message in the new code block.**

why this simple change will not work. what am i missing here.

Comment: code sample would help

Comment: added the old and new code block

Comment: do you have console errors? this code should work

Comment: you don't declare `errString` and your alert is alerting `errstring` and not `errString`. Otherwise your code does work in snippets at least.

Comment: no console errors also. this one block is not working in a big script on over 4k lines.

Comment: case sensitivity is my bad. i typed it wrongly in the question but my original code has proper case.

Comment: errString is already declared in the top of the script.

Comment: Since you mention there aren't any error message and the "New Block" sample most definitely runs "alert" all the time, you probably aren't actually running that code. You should try debugging and see why you don't enter that function. Use `debugger();` and see how that goes `:)`.
Alternatively, perhaps you disallowed the "alerts" to pop up in your browser or whichever environment you test your code on!

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared all these variables you are using ? That's only what I do to make your code works:

```js
var objRDF = '', objRDT = '', errString = '', RDT = 0, RDF = 1;
if (objRDF == '' || objRDT == '') {
  errString = errString + "message here";
 }
if (RDT < RDF) {
  errString = errString + "message here";
}
alert(errString);  //<--- not errstring
```